# Rails locale file wont load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, yaml

I'm translating my website in both English and French.
I have a lot of locale files in my config/locales directory organized into subfolders.

All of my files are loading properly except one and I just don't know why.

Here is the content of my file:

```
fr:
  categories:
    index:
      page_title: "Toutes les catégories"
      page_description: "Liste de toutes les catégories de tutoriels."
```

In my categories controller's index view, I have the following call:

```
%h1= t('.page_title')
```

And I keep getting

> translation missing: fr.categories.index.page_title

Have you any hints about this issue?

---

Okay, finally found the issue.

I have the following in another file:

```
fr:
  categories: "Catégories"
```

This key was clashing with the one in my other file that's why the sub-keys could not be found.

Comment: Did you try the full path aka `categories.index.page_title`?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is trying to load all files in `locale` subfolders, you can just add the following line to `application.rb`:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**/*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Worked well for me on Rails `5.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to your organisation in subfolders. I see in my application.rb `# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.`

You need to either stop using subfolders, or change `config.i18n.load_path` so that it looks recursively into locales/**/*.rb,yml

Comment: That's what I did. All my files in any subfolders are loaded except this one. That's why I don't understand.

Comment: Hm, weird. Have you relaunched the server since? Is the file name a simple name (no spaces, accents, etc)? I know, dumb questions. But that's all I can think of right now.

Comment: Yes, server relaunched multiple time, I have tried on multiples machines, same result. The file name is as simple as fr.yml and it's path is config/locale/controllers/categories/fr.yml

Comment: Ok so your file is either not loaded, or its content not read. Do you have an english version of this file, and is it loaded properly? If yes, I think the content is not read, and my only guess here is it's an encoding issue.. But I'm reaching here, I guess you have accents in your other french files that are working.

Comment: Same thing for my english file. When I run `rake i18n:missing_keys`, those contained in my file are not shown. I wrote those 2 files with Sublime Text and they're encoded in UTF-8 just as the other files which are loaded. Maybe 'categories' is causing an issue despite that I've not head it's a reserved word...

Comment: Duh. Have you tried moving the translations into a file you are sure is loaded, to check wether it's the content or the file itself the problem ?

Comment: Oh, great. I was really curious about this one :)